# ASP.NET modify connectionstring at runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, connection-string

I need to change dataset connectionstrings to point to different DBs at run time.

I've looked at a number of solutions however they all seem to be related to WinForms or web *application* projects or other technology slightly different than what I'm using, so I haven't figured out how apply them.

The application is like a discussion.  It's a web *site* project based on code originally written under VS2005, and there's no budget (or personal talent!) for major changes at this time.  The app is written in vb.net; I can understand answers in c#. I'm working in VS2013.

The app has three typed datasets pointing to one MDF, call it "MainDB.mdf".  There are dozens of tableadapters among the three datasets.

I'm going to deploy the app it as an "alpha/demo" version.  I would like to use the same code base for all users, and a separate physical version of MainDB for each user, to reduce chances that the users crash each other.

The initial demo access URL will contain query string information that I can use to connect the user with the right physical database file.  I should be able to identify the database name and thus the connection string parameters from the query string information (probably using replace on a generic connection string).  If necessary I could use appsettings to store fully formed connection strings, however, I would like to avoid that.

I would like to be able to change the connection strings for all the datasets at the time that the entry point pages for the app are accessed.

Changing the tableadapter connection strings at each instantiation of the tableapters would require too much code change (at least a couple of hundred instantiations); I'd just make complete separate sites instead of doing that.  That's the fall back position if I can't dynamically change the connectionstrings at runtime (or learn some other way to make this general scheme work).

Any suggestions on how to approach this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Per comments, here is a sample instantiation of tableadapter

```
    Public Shared Sub ClearOperCntrlIfHasThisStaff( _
    varSesnID As Integer, varWrkprID As Integer)

    Dim TA As GSD_DataSetTableAdapters.OPER_CNTRLTableAdapter

    Dim DR As GSD_DataSet.OPER_CNTRLRow
    DR = DB.GetOperCntrlRowBySesnID(varSesnID)

    If IsNothing(DR) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If DR.AField = varWrkprID Then
        DR.AField = -1
        TA.Update(DR)
        DR.AcceptChanges()
    End If

End Sub
```

UPDATE:  Below is the test code I tried in a test site to modify the connectionString in a single instantiation of a tableadapter.  It feeds a simple gridview.  I tried calling this from Page_Load, Page_PreLoad, ObjectDataSource_Init, and Gridview_Databind.  At the concluding response.writes, the wrkNewConnString looks changed to TestDB2, and the TA.Connection.ConnectionString value looks changed to TestDB2, but the displayed gridview data is still from TestDB1.  Maybe it needs to be called from somewhere else?

```
Sub ChangeTableAdapter()
    Dim wrkNewConnStr As String = ""
    Dim wrkSel As Integer
    wrkSel = 2

    wrkNewConnStr = wrkNewConnStr & "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;"
    wrkNewConnStr = wrkNewConnStr & "AttachDbFilename=D:\9000_TestSite\App_Data\TESTDB1.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

    Select Case wrkSel
        Case 1
            wrkNewConnStr = wrkNewConnStr.Replace("TESTDB1", "TESTDB1")
        Case 2
            wrkNewConnStr = wrkNewConnStr.Replace("TESTDB1", "TESTDB2")

        Case 3
            wrkNewConnStr = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=test01;"
            wrkNewConnStr = wrkNewConnStr & " User ID=testuser1; Password=testuserpw1"
    End Select

    Try
        Dim TA As New DataSetTableAdapters.NamesTableAdapter
        TA.Connection.ConnectionString = wrkNewConnStr

        Response.Write("1 - " & wrkNewConnStr)
        Response.Write("<br/>")
        Response.Write("2 - " & TA.Connection.ConnectionString)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim exmsg As String = ex.Message
        Response.Write(exmsg)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The connection string:

```
      <add name="TestDB1ConnectionString" 
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=D:\9000_TestSite\App_Data\TESTDB1.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

UPDATE:  the following post has lots of solutions, however, they seem to focus on web application projects, that have a project file with settings, which this web site project does not.

[link with possible solutions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7483b816-be7a-4204-a4d3-cfb14b2aae26/how-to-dynamically-change-connection-string-in-generated-dataset-class?forum=adodotnetdataset)

UPDATE:  this next link was brought to my attention, and in working on it I did get it to work, however, it still relies either on having a web application project (with project file) or modifying each table adapter as they are instantiated.  So, while I'm not going to implement it, I believe that is the technical answer.

[modifying connection strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/04/06/changing-the-connection-string-for-typed-datasets.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at the adapter pattern, your problem is simple so is the solution

Comment: _(Changing the tableadapter connection strings at each instantiation of the tableapters would require too much code change (at least a couple of hundred instantiations))_ Could you please provide us with a code sample? How are the adapters initialized right now?

Comment: Sample use of tableadapter added to original post

Comment: @Dalorzo: I'm what I would call an experienced amateur programmer.  So, unfortunately, not sure where to go with your comment;  if you could provide more information, maybe I could explore that.

Comment: Though I suppose I could search for all uses of "tableadapter" and add a call to a routine that would change the connection string, if that would work, and if it could be made fairly generic.  I'd have to think about the impact on the project and the risk of "breaking" the code.  Then I could make the routine "do nothing: if/when it moves to production.  Although I expect a thorough rewrite at that point.  Question is, would that work?  I tried a test case of changing a single tableadapter at run time and could not get it to work.

Comment: Update: Added the test code that I used to modify a single instantiation of a table adapter, in a test site, without success.

Comment: Added a link with several solutions, that don't seem to apply to web site projects vs web application projects.

Comment: Added another link to another solution, and some concluding thoughts:  it's possible, just not practical for my particular situation.

Comment: Whether the examples are winforms, web apps, web sites or whatever has no bearing on _opening a connection to a database and retrieving data_ so I'd look at those examples a bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry if this answer is too late, but I have exactly the same problem and eventually came up with a solution using Reflection.

My solution was to "save" a new default value for the connection string in the settings at run time, which means any further use of the table adapter uses the the new connection string.

It should be noted the term "save" is misleading as the new value is lost when the application closes.

Have tested and worked perfectly.

```
    public void ChangeDefaultSetting(string name, string value)
    {
        if (name == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        Assembly a = typeof({Put the name of a class in the same assembly as your settings class here}).Assembly;
        Type t = a.GetType("{Put the full name of your settings class here}");
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = t.GetProperty("Default");
        System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase def = propertyInfo.GetValue(null) as System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase;

        //change the "defalt" value and save it to memory
        def[name] = value;
        def.Save();
    }
```